# bash, parsing part of a file

Tags: bash, parsing

Imagine a text file something like the following:

```
Case 4
case 4.1
a 3
a 5
a 7
a 1
a 9
a 4
endcase 4.1
//
.
.
. Do things that dont get parsed
.
.
//
case 4.2
a 1
b 3
a 6
b7 
endcase 4.2
endcase 4
//
.
.
.
. More things
.
.
//
case 5
.
.
.
.
endcase 5
```

which contains the values of multiple variables at different points in time. Eg, case 4 concerns variable a and b. How do I extract only the lines between say case 4.1 and endcase 4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk, for example:

```
awk '/^case 4.1/,/^endcase 4.1/' ./your_file
```

Comment: awk '/^case 4.1/,/^endcase 4.1/' ./your_file | while read line; do; something; done;

Does that look like it might work?

Comment: yep that will process the result lines, but keep in mind the expression will also include in the output "case 4.1" and "endcase 4.1". You might want to grep -v them if you want a clean output.

Comment: My text file isn't nearly as clean as the sample one above, There is further parsing needed, but that bit I know how to do... I really need to learn awk..

Comment: you can also check out perl as an option: http://www.llc.manchester.ac.uk/intranet/ug/useful-links/perl/ if you have the time...

Comment: Unfortunately, not an option at this time. Has to be bash because I'm adding to existing work.

Answer (score 2):

To match lines between two patterns, use:

```
/case 4\.1/,/endcase 4\.1/
```

to print the line matching this pattern:

```
sed -n '/case 4\.1/,/endcase 4\.1/p' yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n';
line="$(cat case.txt)"

for lines in ${line}
do

        if [[ $lines =~ case(.*)$ ]]; then
                caseid=`echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`
                echo "----> $caseid"
        fi

        if  [[ $lines =~ endcase ]]; then
                caseid="0"
        fi
                if [ "$caseid" != "0" ]; then
                        echo $caseid -- $lines;
                fi

done
```

this will parse through the file and for each case print out the values - if you wanted to parse through rather than looking for a specific case

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print a specific sub-case block:

```
awk -v casenum=4.1 '
  $1 == "case" && $2 == casenum {prnt = 1}
  prnt
  $1 == "endcase" && $2 == casenum {prnt = 0}
' filename
```

if you want to print all subcases:

```
awk '
  $1 == "case" && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ {casenum = $2; prnt = 1}
  prnt
  $1 == "endcase" && $2 == casenum {prnt = 0}
' filename
```