# File parsing in bash. separating different sub sections

Tags: linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash, parsing part of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723575/bash-parsing-part-of-a-file)

```
Case 4
case 4.1
a 3
a 5
a 7
a 1
a 9
a 4
endcase 4.1
//
.
.
. Do things that don't get parsed
.
.
//
case 4.2 
a 1
b 3
a 6
b7 
endcase 4.2
endcase 4 
//
.
.
.
. More things
.
.
// 
case 5
.
.
.
.
endcase 5
```

Considering the sample file above. the command
    awk '/^case 4.2/,/^endcase 4.2/' ./my_file.txt

will extract from the file only the information contained within the required section.
How then, would I extract from this smaller section Only the lines that start with "a"? My file is somewhat more complex than the sample, but I think the logic will still apply.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with sed:

```
sed -n -e '/^case 4[.]2/,/^endcase 4[.]2/ { /^a/p }' my_file.txt
```

The `-n` tells sed only to print lines that we tell it to. The curly braces are a group of commands, and by the address prefix used (which is the same as the one you used in awk) we guarantee that they only execute in the case block. The group only contains a single command, which is the "p" print command. However, we prefix this command with another address prefix. This one tells it to execute only if the line starts with "a".

By nesting the addresses, we can execute commands that are between the "case 4.2" and "endcase 4.2" lines, **and** that start with the "a" text.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: What about `case 5`? and if any other case like `case 6`, `case 7` and so on..???

Comment: What do you mean? From my understanding of the question, it is required to print lines that are in case 4.2 *and* start with "a". Is this incorrect?

Comment: The OP mentioned `4.2` but his data file example also contains a `case 5`. Would he not want the lines under `case 5`? if not then I guess its ok.

Answer (score 1):

with awk, I thought this might work, but it doesn't

```
awk '/^case 4.2/,/^endcase 4.2/ && /^a/' filename
```

Instead, this works:

```
awk '/^case 4.2/,/^endcase 4.2/ {if (/^a/) print}' filename
```